# Yahoo YQL missing industry "Industrial Metals & Minerals"

Tags: historical-data, yahoofinance

When I issue the following query

`select * from yahoo.finance.industry where id="133"`

I get the following results

`{
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2014-12-03T11:36:47Z",
  "lang": "it",
  "results": {
   "industry": {
    "id": "133",
    "name": ""
   }
  }
 }
}`

Is this a missing data from YQL?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is no data for 133. If you want to know which sectors have data try this

```
select * from yahoo.finance.industry where id in (select industry.id from yahoo.finance.sectors)
```

For example sector 111 has data

```
<industry id="111" name="Synthetics">
        <company name="American Nano Silicon Technolo" symbol="ANNO"/>
        <company name="Axiall Corporation" symbol="AXLL"/>
        <company name="BioLargo, Inc." symbol="BLGO"/>
        <company name="GelTech Solutions, Inc." symbol="GLTC"/>
        <company name="Kraig Biocraft Laboratories, I" symbol="KBLB"/>
        <company name="Lightbridge Corp." symbol="LTBR"/>
        <company name="Lizhan Environmental Corp." symbol="LZENF"/>
        <company name="Sino Clean Energy Inc" symbol="SCEI"/>
        <company name="Trinseo SA" symbol="TSE"/>
    </industry>
```

Hope that helps